# CSS transition making page too wide

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to make a box slide in from the left of my page while in the viewport, however it's making my page too wide and I can't get it to reverse once out of the viewport once I've scrolled past it. This is what I have:

```
.box {
 background: #2db34a;
 border-radius: 6px;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 95px;
 line-height: 95px;
 text-align: center;
 transition-property: background;
 transition-duration: 1s;
 transition-timing-function: linear;
 width: 95px;
 margin-top: 500px;
 }


#slide {
position: absolute;
right: -100px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: blue;
overflow: hidden;
animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
animation-delay: 1s
-webkit-animation: moveToRight .6s ease both;
animation: moveToRight .6s ease both;
-webkit-animation: moveFromRight .6s ease both;
animation: moveFromRight .6s ease both;
 }

@-webkit-keyframes moveToRight { 
 from { }
 to { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
 }
@keyframes moveToRight { 
  from { }
 to { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); transform: translateX(100%); }
 }

@-webkit-keyframes moveFromRight {
 from { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
  }
@keyframes moveFromRight {
 from { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); transform: translateX(100%); }
}

</style>

</head>


<body>

<div id="slide" class="box">Box</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I can't use any plug-ins to do this either.

Comment: Does putting `overflow: hidden` on the `.box` if that's the `#slide` container help?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: I just fixed the page size issue by adding a wrapper, still can't fix the scrolling issue though.

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well or a working JSFiddle so i can understand what you're trying to achieve?